# PyQt5 push a button with a keyboard stroke

Tags: python, pyqt5, shortcut, qpushbutton, qtabwidget

I am developping a PyQt5 gui.
I try to implement a push button that would be pushed when I hit a key on my keyboard. Let say 'K'.
I have tried this but it is not working. Any thoughts?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout,QTabWidget, QFileDialog, QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QKeySequence
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

Ui_TabWidget, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtcreator_file)

class TabWidget(QTabWidget, Ui_TabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        Ui_TabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonGood.clicked.connect(lambda : self.writeOutliers(False))
        self.pushButtonOutliers.clicked.connect(lambda : self.writeOutliers(True))

        self.shortcut_open = QShortcut(QKeySequence('K'), self)
        self.shortcut_open.activated.connect(lambda : self.writeOutliers(True))
```

Comment: Right now your code should theoretically work. Is it possible that you also have some text input somewhere, like a QLineEdit or QTextEdit, and that field has keyboard focus?

Comment: indeed. But I do not know how to unselect the field

Comment: try to give the main window keyboard focus with self.setFocus()

Comment: @user1885349 Using a single key shortrcut when text fields are on the same ui is rarely a good thing, and from the UX perspective is just a terrible idea. You *could* use `clearFocus()` on the text field or try to use `setFocus()` on the window upon display as suggested by Vasco, but then the problem remains: even assuming that the user clearly knows that there's a single-key shortcut for letter K, that would create confusion: how to "reactivate" the shortcut again after editing a text field? What if they think they clicked on a text field but they missed, and type the letter k by mistake?

Comment: good idea i shall make a ctrl+k. I tried the setFocus() but I got: 
`app.py", line 293, in <module>`
    `window = TabWidget()`

  `File app.py", line 50, in __init__`
   `self.pushButtonGood.clicked.connect(self.setFocus())`

`TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'`

should I call something else?

Comment: I agree with @musicamante. It's not a good idea, since it can confuse the user. But if you really want to do it, give the MainWindow focus after clicking a button or editing a Lineedit can be a way. Now, the self.setFocus() should be placed inside the self.writeOutliers function, in order to do whatever you need, plus returning the focus back to the MainWindow.

Comment: @user1885349 signal connections must have a *callable* as argument (while the argument *can* be a function, that function should return a callable anyway, and `setFocus()` obviously doesn't). So, it should be `self.pushButtonGood.clicked.connect(self.setFocus)` (no matched parentheses on `setFocus`!).

Comment: the '()' killed me thanks! Although the 

        `self.shortcut_open = QShortcut(QKeySequence('Ctrl+O'), self)`
        `self.shortcut_open.activated.connect(self.on_open)`
        
    `def on_open():`
        `print('shortcut')`
Does not work, I have been able to define the 'ctr+K' shortcut with QTdesigner. Probleme solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QKeySequence
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

Ui_TabWidget, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtcreator_file)

class TabWidget(QTabWidget, Ui_TabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        Ui_TabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButtonGood.clicked.connect(lambda : self.writeOutliers(False))
        self.pushButtonOutliers.clicked.connect(lambda : self.writeOutliers(True))

        self.pushButtonGood.clicked.connect(self.setFocus)
```

`self.setFocus` get the keyboard focus elsewhere that edittext at the first click on `pushButtonGood`.

Then define the key shortcut of the buttons in the QTdesigner with the "Editeur de Propriétés".

Do a complexe shortcut 'ctrl+K'